Kernel restarting issue with ChromaDB code
I'm working with ChromaDB, and my kernel keeps restarting when I try to add documents to a collection. Below is the code that is causing the problem:
collection.add(
    documents=[
        "This document is about New York",
        "This document os about Tunisia"
    ],
    ids = ['id1','id2']
)

I ran the above code to add documents to a ChromaDB collection. I expected the documents to be added without any issues. However, the kernel crashes and restarts each time.
Why the kernel might be crashing during this operation and how to fix this?

Try running the code in kaggle
